# Fields closed under countable additions?

Tags: field-theory

So I was learning about fields today and I came across the property that fields are closed under addition. That is, if $v_2,v_1 \in $ **F** ,then: 
$ v_1 + v_2 \in$ **F** 
Similarly, I we can say that:
 
$ v_1 + v_2 +v_3\in$ **F** 
My question is can we extend this by saying: 
$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} v_n \in$ **F** ?
Where $v_n \in $ **F** 
I am pretty sure it won't hold for uncountably infinite additions, but will this be true for countably infinite addition as shown?

Comment: How would you define the sum?

Comment: What does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty v_n$ even *mean*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the field $\mathbb R$, and the countable sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}1$.

---

*Additional comments:*

The problem is that an infinite "sum" is not a sum at all. It is definitely NOT an infinite number of repeated additions. It is the limit of the sequence of finite sums (each of which IS an honest-to-goodness sum, and is an element of the field).

For your sum to exist in an arbitrary field, you would need to be able to define such a limit as a member of that field.

In the counterexample I gave, the partial sums are just $S_k = \overbrace{1+1+\cdots + 1}^{\textrm{$k$ terms}} = k$, but $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}S_k$ does not exist as an element of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: That was silly so me, great explanation.